# Best approach to communicate C++/Python and Front-End

Tags: c++, websockets, reactjs

I work with Computer Vision applications, mainly in Python and C++. Recently, I get involved with a customer that wants to create a UI based on React JS to visualize the results of our software in real time.

I have an object detection software that will read the streaming of an IP Camera, and apply the AI model to detect the objects. This application is written in C++.

Initially, what I designed is to send the image with the bounding boxes drawn on it through ZeroMQ using a communication socket. Then, in React.JS, I receive that data using ZMQ for JavaScript.

This application works fine with the constraints that I have. However, I'm not sure if this is the best practice or best solution.

So I wanted to ask what are other methods or best practices when dealing with this kind of problem? I mean, the problem here is to send data from one language to another language.

@edit
Here, for `best` I mean a faster way or a common practice in this kind of application.

Comment: Please define "best".

Comment: I believe that best, in my point of view, would be a faster way or a common practice in the field. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> best solution [?]

In the current setup you do some backend cloud computation
to detect objects annotated with bounding boxes,
and send the .PNG pixels through a low latency 0MQ
pub-sub infrastructure for display by the client.
ZeroMQ has some very attractive rendezvous properties
so server hosts and clients can come / go / reboot
and the larger system remains available, offering its services.

Is this "best" ?

Maybe not the very best, but in my view it seems pretty close.

You are requesting that SO contributors propose some alternate
setup that is faster or more common.
IDK, maybe Kafka pub-sub?
It has a very convenient ability to replay all events,
during development edit-run cycles or even when
a trouble-shooter replays production events.
Is it clearly "better"? Maybe. Hard to say.
Your current approach seems pretty standard,
seems like a perfectly nice choice of appropriate tools
for the use case at hand.

An alternative perspective is: "should we be shipping
all those pixels around?"
That is, maybe the client already has video images locally available.
Consider sending just a distilled summary in JSON format,
such as "found two objects, located at bbox1 and bbox2."

Stick with what you have, is my view.

Comment: I got your point of view. All rely on what are the constraints and etc. Thanks!